# List does not show duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need all values, duplicate or not.

```
=INDEX(CCT!$HA$4:$HA23,MATCH(0,IF("Yes"=CCT!$BM$4:$BM23,COUNTIF($O$9:O9,CCT!$HA$4:$HA23),""),0))
```

This works great but when dragged down, duplicates are removed where as I need to display all including duplicates.

Comment: Match will only return the first 0 in the result set. If you want additional to be returned perhaps consider returning either blank or the row number, then grab the row number using `SMALL()` pretty busy so can't knock up an answer right now, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a classic 'list unique with criteria' formula. Here is one to 'list with criteria'.

```
=INDEX(CCT!HA$4:HA23, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$20)/(BM$4:BM$23="yes"), ROW(1:1)))
```

I didn't include an IFERROR wrapper to avoid showing errors when matches ran out  as your original didn't have one.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jeeped but this one seems to just return blank cell??

Comment: What part of the above sample image did I get wrong? I tried to interpret your ranges and criteria the best I could. I guess the formula was intended for O10, not O4 but that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Not sure, will your example return text or just numbers?

Comment: It will return whatever is in the cell; text, numbers, errors, booleans, etc.

Comment: How do I attach a screenshot and I will post what I am working on?